# Cantor Sets in perfect sets in the Real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, cantor-set

My thesis is related with the Cantor sets. I was reading a lot of papers, blogs, etc, in order to look for the mean properties of these sets.

In one blog a read a proposition.

''Every perfect set contains a Cantor set''.

This proposition was without proof, so I wonder if this proposition is true or if you have any ideas of how to prove or papers or something.

All your ideas are very welcome!!

Comment: Check this out: https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/perfect-sets-and-cantor-sets-ii/

Answer (score 6):

If $P$ is a perfect subset of the real numbers, show that there exist $a < b < c < d$ such that $P \cap [a,b]$ and $P \cap [c,d]$ are both perfect.
Let $P_1 = (P \cap [a,b]) \cup (P \cap [c,d])$.  Repeat this process with each of $P \cap [a,b]$ and $P \cap [c,d]$, obtaining $P_2 \subset P_1$ consisting of intersections of $P$ with 4 intervals, $P_3 \subset P_2$
consisting of intersections of $P$ with 8 intervals, .... and making sure the lengths of the intervals approach $0$.  The intersection of all the $P_i$ will be a Cantor set.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can prove this in the most general case. Take any finite set $S$ with the indiscrete topology. Then $S$ will be a perfect subset, indeed a perfect space. Now define a *Cantor Set* to be a set that is topologically isomorphic to the usual construction of removing thirds of the real line. Every Cantor set must then be uncountable, so there can be no Cantor set inside of $S$, since $S$ is finite.

Edit: Just re-read the title, but you can also do the same thing with a finite or countable subset of the reals if you allow the indiscrete topology. So unless you mean also the usual Euclidean/open ball topology on the reals, the general claim will also fail. But I think you should be able to prove it assuming that topology.

Comment: One wants to assume the space is Polish, I think.  But the question's title does refer to the real numbers.

Comment: Yup that sounds like a reasonable assumption. But it's worth pointing out that whether a set is perfect or not depends on the underlying topology, and the general claim "perfect set implies having a Cantor set" is false if you have other topologies in mind, by this simple cardinality argument.